# Getting computername in Azure Automation DSC

Tags: dsc, azure-automation

I´m trying to use Azure Automation Pull server to add DSC configuration to a VM. Normally you can get the name of the current machine with the environment variable `$env:COMPUTERNAME` - i.e. like this:

```ps1
xComputer JoinDomain
{ 
    Name  = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    DomainName = $ConfigurationData.NonNodeData.DomainDetails.DomainName             
    Credential    = $domainAdminCredential  
}
```

But when using Azure Automation `$env:COMPUTERNAME` seems to always return **CLIENT** regardless of the current machine name. What is the best/most recommended approach to dynamically get the name of the current VM within the DSC configuration when using Azure Automation?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Thomas

Comment: You don't need to specify a computername here.  This is only done if you want to change the name of a machine while you domain join.

Comment: The Name property is mandatory, so cannot be omitted.

Comment: Ah, I was wrong!  But I now recall how to do this, so I'll add my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary a DSC configuration is applied as under:

1. Author the configuration in PowerShell
2. Compile the configuration - this generates a mof file
3. Deliver the mof file to the LocalConfigurationManager (LCM) which enacts the same

The code specified actually gets the name of the computer in step #2. Note that #2 can happen in a different computer than the one where you want to apply the configuration. In this case it happens to be the one on the AA service side.

Unfortunately, at the moment there is no way to obtain the name of the computer in which the configuration is executing unless you choose to use the script resource. So in summary you can either specify the computer name via configuration data or do the domain join using a script resource

Answer (score 1):

To piggy-back on @NanaLakshaman's answer, let's paramaterize this configuration.

For the sake of ease of understanding, I'm going to pretend that you're only configuring the computer name and domain join.

```
configuration DomainJoin
{
 param
(
    [string[]]$NodeName ='localhost',
    [string]$DomainName,  
    [string]$credential
) 

#Import the required DSC Resources
Import-DscResource -Module xComputer

Node $NodeName
{ #ConfigurationBlock 


    xComputer JoinDomain
        {
            Name       = $nodename
            DomainName = $DomainName             
            Credential = $Credential  

        }
    }
}
```

Now, compile it into memory by hitting F5 or running the script (in Azure Automation, you'd be running the script).  Then, call the config like you would a function to generate the new Desired State Configuration. *Here is where you can specify the local computer name*.

```
DomainJoin -NodeName $env:ComputerName -DomainName SomeDomain -Credential (Get-Cred)
```

This will create a new `configuration.mof` file, which you can then apply using:

```
Start-DscConfiguration -ComputerName localhost -Wait -Force -Verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to provide the computer name in the configuration data.

An example of how to supply the configuration data is here in Azure Automation is here, along with an example of how to use the `NodeName` in a resource:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-dsc-compile/

**Also**, the particular use you mention, should not require the name to be supplied.  I have filed an issue for that here:
https://github.com/PowerShell/xComputerManagement/issues/29